# Conversion failed error when joining on a table with a created field

Tags: sql-server-2012, inner-join

I have a table (DateDimension) with a field (MonthYear) that is a varchar.  The values look like this:

12 2017
11 2017
10 2017
9 2017

I have another table (SupplierData) with a field (GR Date) that is a varchar that I am using to create a field (ReportingPeriod) to use as a join to the DateDimension table.

Here is the code for ReportingPeriod:

```
ReportingPeriod = Cast(DatePart(Month, [GR Date]) As varchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(DatePart(Year, [GR Date]) As Varchar(4))
```

When I try to create my join like this:

```
INNER JOIN dbo.DateDimension dd ON dd.MonthYear = a.ReportingPeriod
```

I receive this error:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your error is caused by a bad value for `GR Date`. The best solution is to make sure you're using correct datatypes, but you could also use `try_cast()` instead as it will return `null` instead of throwing an error when the value can't be converted.

```
ReportingPeriod = Cast(DatePart(Month, try_cast([GR Date] as date)) As varchar(2)) 
  + ' ' 
  + Cast(DatePart(Year, try_cast([GR Date] as date)) As Varchar(4))
```

---

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)

Comment: Yes, it was bad data.  Although SSMS tells me try_cast is not a recognized built-in function name, it works.